# How do I use extended characters in Python's curses library?

Tags: python, curses

I've been reading tutorials about Curses programming in Python, and many refer to an ability to use extended characters, such as line-drawing symbols. They're characters > 255, and the curses library knows how to display them in the current terminal font.

Some of the tutorials say you use it like this:

```
c = ACS_ULCORNER
```

...and some say you use it like this:

```
c = curses.ACS_ULCORNER
```

(That's supposed to be the upper-left corner of a box, like an L flipped vertically)

Anyway, regardless of which method I use, the name is not defined and the program thus fails. I tried "import curses" and "from curses import *", and neither works.

Curses' window() function makes use of these characters, so I even tried poking around on my box for the source to see how *it* does it, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `curses/__init__.py`:

> Some constants, most notably the `ACS_*`
>   ones, are only added to the C
>   `_curses` module's dictionary after `initscr()` is called.  (Some versions
>   of SGI's curses don't define values
>   for those constants until `initscr()`
>   has been called.)  This wrapper
>   function calls the underlying C
>   `initscr()`, and then copies the
>   constants from the
>   `_curses` module to the curses package's dictionary.  Don't do '`from curses
>   import *`' if you'll be needing the
>   `ACS_*` constants.

In other words:

```
>>> import curses
>>> curses.ACS_ULCORNER
exception
>>> curses.initscr()
>>> curses.ACS_ULCORNER
>>> 4194412
```

Comment: Thanks for that; to dump the available ACS defines from Python's `curses`, one could use: `python -c 'import pprint,inspect,curses ; curses.initscr() ; outstr= pprint.pformat(inspect.getmembers(curses)); curses.endwin() ; print(outstr)' | grep ACS`. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

you have to set your local to all, then encode your output as utf-8 as follows:

```
import curses
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')    # set your locale

scr = curses.initscr()
scr.clear()
scr.addstr(0, 0, u'\u3042'.encode('utf-8'))
scr.refresh()
# here implement simple code to wait for user input to quit
scr.endwin()
```

output:
あ

Answer (score 4):

I believe the below is appropriately related, to be posted under this question. Here I'll be using [utfinfo.pl](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/utfinfo.pl) (see also on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/581523/program-to-check-look-up-utf-8-unicode-characters-in-string-on-command-line/581529#581529)).

First of all, for standard ASCII character set, the Unicode code point and the byte encoding is the same:

```
$ echo 'a' | perl utfinfo.pl 
Char: 'a' u: 97 [0x0061] b: 97 [0x61] n: LATIN SMALL LETTER A [Basic Latin]
```

So we can do in Python's `curses`:

```
window.addch('a')
window.border('a')
```

... and it works as intended

However, if a character is above basic ASCII, then there are differences, which [`addch` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.addch) don't necessarily make explicit. First, I can do:

```
window.addch(curses.ACS_PI)
window.border(curses.ACS_PI)
```

... in which case, in my `gnome-terminal`, the Unicode character 'π' is rendered. However, if you inspect `ACS_PI`, you'll see it's an integer number, with a value of 4194427 (0x40007b); so the following will also render the same character (or rater, glyph?) 'π':

```
window.addch(0x40007b)
window.border(0x40007b)
```

To see what's going on, I grepped through the `ncurses` source, and found the following:

```
#define ACS_PI      NCURSES_ACS('{') /* Pi */  
#define NCURSES_ACS(c)  (acs_map[NCURSES_CAST(unsigned char,c)])
#define NCURSES_CAST(type,value) static_cast<type>(value)
#lib_acs.c: NCURSES_EXPORT_VAR(chtype *) _nc_acs_map(void): MyBuffer = typeCalloc(chtype, ACS_LEN);
#define typeCalloc(type,elts) (type *)calloc((elts),sizeof(type))
#./widechar/lib_wacs.c: { '{',  { '*',  0x03c0 }},  /* greek pi */
```

Note here:

```
$ echo '{π' | perl utfinfo.pl 
Got 2 uchars
Char: '{' u: 123 [0x007B] b: 123 [0x7B] n: LEFT CURLY BRACKET [Basic Latin]
Char: 'π' u: 960 [0x03C0] b: 207,128 [0xCF,0x80] n: GREEK SMALL LETTER PI [Greek and Coptic]
```

... neither of which relates to the value of 4194427 (0x40007b) for `ACS_PI`.

Thus, when `addch` and/or `border` see a character above ASCII (basically an `unsigned int`, as opposed to `unsigned char`), they (at least in this instance) use that number **not** as Unicode code point, or as UTF-8 encoded bytes representation - but instead, they use it as a look-up index for `acs_map`-ping function (which ultimately, however, *would* return the Unicode code point, even if it emulates VT-100). That is why the following specification:

```
window.addch('π') 
window.border('π')
```

will fail in Python 2.7 with `argument 1 or 3 must be a ch or an int`; and in Python 3.2 would render simply a space instead of a character. When we specify `'π'`. we've actually specified the UTF-8 encoding [0xCF,0x80] - but even if we specify the Unicode code point:

```
window.addch(0x03C0) 
window.border0x03C0)
```

... it simply renders nothing (space) in both Python 2.7 and 3.2.

That being said - the function `addstr` *does* accept UTF-8 encoded strings, and works fine:

```
window.addstr('π')
```

... but for borders - since `border()` apparently handles characters in the same way `addch()` does - we're apparently out of luck, for anything not explicitly specified as an `ACS` constant (and there's not that many of them, either).

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: How come when I std.addch(y, x, curses.ACS_PI), it prints an open curly bracket instead of a PI symbol?